# How do I break out of a recursive void method?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to figure out a seemingly simple problem with this program.  The goal is to rearrange the array in ascending order using a recursive method.  I wrote the main method as well as the recursive method as shown below.  The issue is that for some reason, I can't stop the method, despite having a condition to prevent it from continuing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] a = {9,8,7,6,1,2,5,4};
    recursiveSelectionSort(a, 0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}

public static void recursiveSelectionSort(int[] a, int start){

    int minpos, temp;

//this condition is meant to stop the method
    if (start==(a.length-1))
      return;

    minpos = start;
    for (int i = start; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] < a[minpos])
        minpos = i;
    }
    temp = a[start];
    a[start] = a[minpos];
    a[minpos] = temp;

//this line causes the stack overflow error
    recursiveSelectionSort(a, start++);

  }
```

When I delete the recursiveSelectionSort(a,start++) statement, I get an output of {1,8,7,6,9,2,5,4}, which is correct.  However, I want this process to continue so they will all eventually be sorted.  When I keep the recursion statement, I get the error.

Comment: I apologize if I had made any spacing or indenting errors.  This is my first time.

Comment: You break with a `return` statement or by hitting the end of the method.  So what are you really trying to ask?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

```
recursiveSelectionSort(a, start++);
```

Doing it this way causes you to first pass `start` to `recursiveSelectionSort` and **then** increment start. `start` will remain the same in every recursive call.

Use

```
recursiveSelectionSort(a, start+1);
```

or if you really like to increment `start` (even if there is no reason to do so), use

```
recursiveSelectionSort(a, ++start);
```

to increment first.